# Converting created_utc values from a .csv file to 'regular' dates using Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, reddit

I have used the PMAW Pushshift API to gather reddit submissions from a specific subreddit, using Python and I want to convert the UTC timestamp to regular dates (date, month, year).
I have saved the submissions in a .csv file, using Panda, with the 'date' of the submissions being created as
"created_utc".
A method I think might work could be the datetime.fromutcstamp method, as shown here:

```
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(created_utc)
print(date.year)
print(date.month)
```

But how exactly I use the method on my .csv file is beyond me, at the time.
Any help is appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Does the CSV have the column "created_utc" which is a `string` and you want to convert it to a `datetime` object? Is that your question? Can you share a sample of the contents of the CSV?

Comment: Sorry, I was being unclear. Each submission has a given 'created_utc' value attached to them. E.g.: 1517905889. I want to convert this UTC-value to a more 'normal' date: Month, day, year. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the pandas library. Depending on your performance needs I'd start with using the [pandas apply method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html)

```
import pandas as pd

def convert_time(UTC_time):
    regular_time = None # Time conversion function
    return regular_time

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df['created_utc'] = df['created_utc'].apply(convert_time)
```

Comment: I will try this! Thank you!